# How to select a <a href> javascript button using selenium java

Tags: java, javascript, button, click

I'm trying to click the "*Add to Shopping Bag*" button by utilising selenium (Java) interface on my AUT, but I'm unable to do so.

**My script as follows:**

```
public void addToBag()
{
     WebElement AddToBag = null;
         List<WebElement> SizeList = driver.findElement(By.className("selection-wrapper")).findElements(By.className("step-wrapper"));
         for(WebElement e : SizeList)
          {
             if (e.getText() == " ")
              {
                if(e.findElement(By.tagName("span")).findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href").contains("javascript:AddToCart()"))
                  {
                      AddToBag = e.findElement(By.tagName("span")).findElement(By.tagName("a"));
                      AddToBag.click();
                      break;
                  }
              }
        } 
       Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

**Source code:**

```
<div class="subitem-steps span-12 last" style="z-index: 890;">`
<div class="item-styles span-12 last" style="z-index: 885;">`
<div class="selection-wrapper" style="z-index: 870;">`
<div class="step-wrapper" style="z-index: 869;">
  <div class="step-wrapper" style="z-index: 863;">
  <div class="step-wrapper" style="z-index: 857;">
  <div class="step-wrapper" style="z-index: 851;">
   <div class="step step4" style="z-index: 850;"/>
    <span class="ui-btn-grey btn-add-to-cart btn-add-to-cart-sel">
       <a href="javascript:AddToCart()" onclick="s_objectID="javascript:AddToCart()_1";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true"/>
</span>
   <div class="external-links" style="z-index: 849;">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare String's :)

Comment: Any ideas what could i use instead. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `" ".equals(e.getText())`

Comment: Thanks a lot...I will try to use it in my script.